# Episode 77 - links instead of a for loop

Tags: linq, loops, terminology, for-loop

In episode 77 Joel and Jeff were discussing using links instead of a for loop.  I looked in Stack Overflow, Google, and Wikipedia but couldn't find any reference to a links construct.  The closest thing I could find was a self referencing linked list which would presumably loop indefinitely.  Is links a feature of the Links programming language?  If not, what was meant by links in this context.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Podcasts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm pretty sure they said [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx).

In .Net it's a pretty useful feature allowing you essentially "select" items from an object collection using syntax that looks suspiciously like SQL:

```
List<Person> personList = // maybe passed into a method or whatever
IEnumerable<Person> filteredList = from p in personList
                                   where p.Age > ageThreshold
                                   select p
return filteredList.ToList<Person>();
```

There's a great Manning book on it: "[LINQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/marguerie/)" and they have some sample downloadable chapters if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that they were talking about using LINQ (Language INtegrated Query), not *links*, to replace `foreach` loops.

```
var stuff = list.Where( l => l.StartsWith( "a" ) ).ToList();
```

or

```
var stuff = (from l in list
            where l.StartsWith("a")
            select l).ToList();
```

vs

```
var stuff = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item.StartsWith("a"))
    {
         stuff.Add( a );
    }
}
```